# Substring a stringRaw from String1 to String2

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, substring, visual-studio-2015

If you didn't really get it what I actually want let me explain you better:

I have a:

```
stringRaw = "<img src=\"http://www.b92.net/news/pics/2015/01/15/111348233854b817af5b4bc991063053_v4 big.jpg\" title=\"\" alt=\"\" />"
```

Now I have to do some kind of substring from `string1 = "<img src=\""` to `string2 = "\" title=\"\" alt=\"\" />"` and have to take what is in the middle of that which will be `stringFinal = "http://www.b92.net/news/pics/2015/01/15/111348233854b817af5b4bc991063053_v4 big.jpg"` in this case.

I can't use `substring` method since I never know how many characters can be in `string1` and `string2` also, seems like `split` method do not work as it should from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639189/vb-net-can-you-split-a-string-by-a-string) question on StackOverFlow.

**edit** For some reason my `stringRaw` has this value: `vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "<img src=""http://www.b92.net/news/pics/2015/02/05/203819435354d39f17d74f0173575440_v4 big.jpg"" title="""" alt="""" />" & vbTab & vbTab`
Anyway, I do what others advised and still I get an error that `Index is out of range`

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Comment: Will the file always be a jpg? Also, is stringRaw just a regular string type?

Comment: Take a look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

Comment: How about `Regex` ((?<=img src=\\").*)(?=\\" title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having issues going after the same characters so I went after text within the string such as "http" and "title=". Here it is in VB:

```
    Dim startIndex As Int32 = stringRaw.IndexOf("http")
    Dim endIndex As Int32 = stringRaw.IndexOf("title=") - 2
    Return stringRaw.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)
```

I used "http" and didn't include "://" just in case you need to get an "https" at some point. I used "title=" instead of "title" in case the word title ever showed up in the link.

Comment: Probably has to do with the fact you can escape double quotes by putting two of them in VB. Like so, `""String in quotes""`

Comment: @Shelby115, that's what I did in my own example. However, if Hoh is actually using vb, then he must have set it somehow but the first line of code in the question doesn't compile for me unless I use "" like you said. Thus, I went after the other characters because that should work either way.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't notice the VB tag right away. Figure worst case scenario, a C# user might run across this question and find my answer helpful.

Comment: This one is actually working like a charm.
I've tried all other solutions, but only this one worked at first try. Thank you a lot @TonyL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code should grab the 'stringFinal' you desire.

```
// Get the index of 'src="'
Int32 startIndex = stringRaw.IndexOf("src=\"");

// Get the substring starting at 'src="' and ending at the first '"' after 'src="'.
stringRaw.Substring(startIndex, stringRaw.IndexOf("\"", startIndex) - startIndex);
```

Oh, sorry just noticed the VB tag. This is C# so the sytnax might be slightly different, but the functions and parameters should still be the same.

I forgot the `- startIndex` I was thinking that `SubString` second parameter was an index instead of count. Try adding that adjustment.

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error "Index was out of range"

Comment: Got too used to JavaScript. Add `- startIndex` to the second parameter, that should fix it. I was thinking SubString's second parameter was stopping index instead of length after first index. It would also be good to check `if (startIndex >= 0) { }` since it'll return -1 if "src=\"" isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regular expression. Something like:

```
Dim stringRaw as String = vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "<img src=""http://www.b92.net/news/pics/2015/02/05/203819435354d39f17d74f0173575440_v4 big.jpg"" title="""" alt="""" />" & vbTab & vbTab
Dim regx as New Regex("src=\""(.*)\""\s+title")
Dim match as Match = regx.Match(stringRaw)

If match.Success
    ' Outputs http://www.b92.net/news/pics/2015/02/05/203819435354d39f17d74f0173575440_v4 big.jpg
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
End If
```

Comment: Hahah that's funny very close to my comment about using `Regex` mine uses a look-behind & look-ahead :)

Comment: Oddly enough when I check your solution in Regex101.com it doesn't match?

Comment: I tested this with LinqPad and it worked. It probably needs to be adjusted to work on Regex101, because of VB.NET syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function ExtractSrcAttribute(ByVal element As String) As String
    Dim startToken As String = "src="""
    Dim endToken As String = """"

    Dim startIndex As Integer = element.IndexOf(startToken) + startToken.Length
    Dim endIndex As Integer = element.IndexOf(endToken, startIndex)

    If startIndex > element.Length OrElse endIndex > element.Length OrElse endIndex < startIndex Then
        'error
    End If

    Return element.SubString(startIndex, endIndex)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment about you could use `Regex` to accomplish this easily. This uses a `Positive-LookBehind` and `Positive-LookAhead`. Please see below for example. This is tried and tested as well.

```
  Dim rgex As New Regex("((?<=src=\\"").*)(?=\\""\s+title=)")
  Dim mtch As Match = rgex.Match(TextBox1.Text)

  If mtch.Success Then
       MessageBox.Show(mtch.Groups(1).Value)
  End If
```

[image]

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)